# SAS/CSV data disappears after VBA formatting

Tags: excel, vba, sas

I am importing a table from a CSV file updated by a SAS script that skips line in order for me to then use VBA to put formulas to get different results and divide them. However, when I Refresh the SAS data from the CSV, I have, for example, my targets, and once the formatting VBA portion comes in, some of the SAS data disappears. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Sounds like there may be a problem with your code, which is why it's usually useful to include it in your question.  There's not much we can offer without knowing what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I thought that would be too complicated..
 I can't post more than 550 chars so here is formatting step1

Comment: *Edit your question* - you can add code there and format it using the `{}` button

Comment: found the error, Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake in SAS code :(